# Is it possible to add ads to an android Widget?

Tags: android-widget

Im trying to make a free version of my widget and i would like to add ads to the widget, is it possible?  if so how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Views in widget apps are limited to :

AnalogClock
Button
Chronometer
ImageButton
ImageView
ProgressBar
TextView
Descendants of these classes are not supported.

So, as there is no webiew, you can't use admobs for instance.

Nevertheless, it looks like other people are trying to address this issue and provide widget with ads too by using simple imageButton : 
http://openx-android.sourceforge.net/

Kind regards,
Stéphane

Answer (score 1):

You could use [StartApp](http://www.startapp.com/).

When someone downloads your app,

> Your user will then get a “search icon” on his home screen, a bookmark link and a browser home page. All directing to our web search URL.

According to the [FAQ Page](http://www.startapp.com/faq/) you get paid either 4 cents for partial integration or 5 cents for full integration just because your app is downloaded.